# How to increase textsize in android while clicking imageview?

Tags: android, textview

I need to develop one android application. What I need here is, when I click on ImageView, size of text size automatically increased. How can I do this?

Following is my code snippet.

```
    ImageView fontincrease = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
       fontincrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count++;
        if (i < 3)
        {
            lblName.textSize += 2;

            i++;
            j = i;
        } }
   });
```

am getting the error: `textSize cannot be resolved or is not a field`

**NOTE:**

Please see [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bbc-news/id377382255?mt=8). See the 2nd image at bottom `-A` and `+A` image is there. Clicking that images means automatically increase and decrease the whole app textview font size. How can I do this in android app?

**EDIT:**

I have to updated my code like below:

```
ImageView positive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.positive);
positive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
      lblName.setTextSize(lblName.getTextSize() + 2);
     }
    });

     Intent in = getIntent();

     // Get XML values from previous intent
     String title = in.getStringExtra("Title");
     lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
     lblName.setText(title);
```

I have to run the app means am getting following error on my console window also my app is force closed.

```
03-11 04:13:13.462: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 04:13:13.462: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.NullPointerException 
03-11 04:13:13.462: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.xmlparsing.SubCate$2.onClick(SubCate.java:27)
```

Comment: please post the logcat logs...

Comment: I thought you should use TextView.setTextSize(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using lblName before declaring it. Try this:

```
Intent in = getIntent();

     // Get XML values from previous intent
     String title = in.getStringExtra("Title");
     lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
     lblName.setText(title);

ImageView positive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.positive);
positive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
      lblName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lblName.getTextSize() + 2)
     }
    });
```

Read more about type value constants here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html

Comment: i have to run the app means am getting following error:03-11 04:13:13.462: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 04:13:13.462: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.xmlparsing.SubCate$2.onClick(SubCate.java:27)

Comment: Hi i have used your code.but my textSize is decreasing only...but i wish to increase the textSize.How can i do ??? please provide me solution for these ???

Comment: Check out my edit now. I changed the lblName.setTextSize method.